# Reading from Honeywell sensors using a tca9548a multiplexer on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c, multiplexing, honeywell

I'm using a tca9548a multiplexer on a raspberry pi in an attempt to read from 3 Honeywell temperature/humidity sensors (hih6021, hih8121, and hih9121). Using the code provided by Adafruit (shown below), I confirmed that the 3 sensors are present (all at address 0x27).

According to the documentation, I can read from each sensor by creating an instance of it using the TCA9548A channel instead of the I2C object. Problem is, I can't find a library for any of those sensors that takes in an i2c object, so I'm at a loss with how to read data from them. So, how can I use the tca9548a to read temperature and humidity from the Honeywell sensors?

```
# This example shows using TCA9548A to perform a simple scan for connected devices
import board
import adafruit_tca9548a

# Create I2C bus as normal
i2c = board.I2C()  # uses board.SCL and board.SDA

# Create the TCA9548A object and give it the I2C bus
tca = adafruit_tca9548a.TCA9548A(i2c)

for channel in range(8):
    if tca[channel].try_lock():
        print("Channel {}:".format(channel), end="")
        addresses = tca[channel].scan()
        print([hex(address) for address in addresses if address != 0x70])
        tca[channel].unlock()
```

Comment: If you are running Linux, why don't you run the kernel driver for multiplexer?

Comment: I'm using a python script to log and compare the data from the sensors, so I need to access the i2c data via script. Google is just surprisingly unhelpful with this.

Comment: What do you mean by python script? Is it OS-less setup?

Comment: No no, it's raspbian running on a pi b+. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Raspbian is Linux, no? Then use in-kernel driver for I2C mux.